# DateRange in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working on application which will fetch report between specific date ranges. There is a possibility of selecting multiple date selections. Usually we have frequency selections as Monthly,Quarterly and Yearly. So Any number of date range(by any frequency type) can be selected without any overlapping periods. Now in the report i need to show the selection date range in terms of month using Postgresql. Is that possible?

eg sample query:

```
select dt, description 
from table1
where (
    dt between '2005-12-26' and '2006-03-26'  
    or dt between '2006-03-27' and '2006-06-25'
    or dt between '2006-06-26' and '2006-12-31'
    or dt between '2007-12-31' and '2008-12-28'
)
group by dt, description
order by dt, description
```

Here

1. Date was selected by choosing monthly  frequency(Jan to March)
2. Date was selected by choosing Quarterly frequency(Q2 of 2006)
3. Date was selected by choosing Quarterly frequency(Q3 and Q4 of 2006)
4. Date was selected by choosing Yearly frequency(2008)

So now my report should look like

```
  Date          DateRange                    Description
2006-01-01    January2006-March2006          XXXXXXXXXXX
2006-08-31    July2006-Dec2006               UUUUUUUUUUU
2008-05-20    January2008-dec2008            ZZZZZZZZZZ
```

Comment: Given that your months and years are defined differently than what the calendar says, a `calendar` table would benefit you immensely.  The PK would be the date, and other fields would specify the year, month, etc, according to your business rules.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a `join`, something like this:

```
   select dt, to_char(r.date1, 'MonthYYYY') || '-' || to_char(r.date2, 'MonthYYYY') as daterange,
          description 
   from table1 t join
        (select '2005-12-26'::date as date1, '2006-03-26'::date as date2 union all         
         select '2006-03-27'::date, '2006-06-25'::date union all
         select '2006-06-26'::date, '2006-12-31'::date union all
         select '2007-12-31'::date, '2008-12-28'::date
        ) r
        on t.dt between r.date1 and r.date2
   group by t.dt, r.date1, r.date2, t.description
   order by dt, description;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon.....It really worked. But a normal report will fetch nearly lakhs of records. What's your opinion on the performance of the query? And one more thing, we are using Broadcast calendar(Broadcast Calendar...this Calendar always starts with Monday). So the first date range 2005-12-26 and 2006-03-26 I'm getting the date range as December 2005-March    2006 where as the user in the front end of the application would have selected as January2006-march2006. Please help on this

Comment: @ChitraThirugnanasambandam . . . For performance questons, you have to try on your data on your systems.